# How to replace given word in whole document in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have word "john" used many times in my document which I want to replace with "mike". How can I achieve that using Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/John/g,'Mike');
$("body").html(replaced);
```

Source:
[Replace text in HTML page with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886319/replace-text-in-html-page-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("john", "mike"); 
});
```

This would work if you need to change any text found in the body element.

Comment: One problem with this, it will completely wipe out all the HTML within the `body` element...