# Jquery - Replace text with tokens without affecting the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to parse a DOM and replace parts of the **text** with tokens, for example detect an email then replace it with {{EMAIL}} string **without changing the HTML**
Given the following HTML (***for example, can be different***):

```
<div dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr; text-align: left;">
   this is <span style="font-style:italic;">my</span>
    email <span title="bla@bla.com" style="font-weight:bold;">bla@bla.com&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

How can I replace just the test portion so it to would be:

```
<div dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr; text-align: left;">
   this is <span style="font-style:italic;">my</span>
    email <span title="bla@bla.com" style="font-weight:bold;">{{EMAIL}}&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean using handlebars? Check it out here: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Convert it how, what is that template supposed to do, and where does it come from?

Comment: Other than showing your work and what you have tried, please elaborate on what exactly you're trying to replace (or what "can be different" means) - is it always the whole content other than that last `&nbsp;` that's supposed to be replaced with the token? And why would you ever put a `&nbsp;` in there anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace text in HTML page with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886319/replace-text-in-html-page-with-jquery)

Comment: thanks for the replies, please see my edits

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan please consider the dupliaction

Comment: Yeah, you want to replace text in HTML with other text. That question's answers show you how. You haven't shown how your question is any different from that one.

Comment: Nop, if an email string exists in a title attribute for example, it will be replaced, which is not the desired output (not affecting the HTML)

Comment: Email address is alway in `span`?

Comment: No this is just an HTML example

Answer (score 1):

you could add an **id="myspan"** to the DOM element that you need to change and with the help of jquery change the **innerHTML** , like so:

### HTML:

```
<div dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr; text-align: left;">
   this is <span style="font-style:italic;">my</span>
    email <span id="myspan" style="font-weight:bold;">{{EMAIL}}&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

### JS:

```
$('#myspan').innerHTML = "{{EMAIL}}&nbsp;";
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however the HTML is not hard coded and could not have any idea on the tag, or have different innerHTML

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 for your reply

Answer (score 1):

You need to select element has `title` attribute and filter selected element using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) that select element has email address in `title` attribute. Then replace email address with new text.

```js
$("div > [title]").filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr("title").match(/^[\w]+@[\w.]+\.[\w]+$/g);
}).text(function(i, text){
    return text.replace(/^[\w]+@[\w.]+\.[\w]+/g, "{{EMAIL}}");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr; text-align: left;">
   this is <span style="font-style:italic;">my</span>
    email <span title="bla@bla.com" style="font-weight:bold;">bla@bla.com&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, title is just an example. I have no control over the input HTML

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz You said *if an email string exists in a title attribute for example, it will be replaced*. The code work for any tag.

Comment: Regex would be the way to go if you need to find all instances of an email address written as text (although you *should* be annotating these tags with data attributes to indicate they contain the text that needs to be changed). Alternatively, I believe you could convert the entire DOM to a string, run regex on the entire string and use match groups to return all nodes containing email address(es) in their content. See the "CheatSheet" link at [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) for more information on match groups and regex.

Comment: Regex could be a solution, but if the entire Dom is a string then email would be replaced in attributes to, when what I want is to replace just the text of a tag

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz `.text()` only return text of element and `text.replace()` only replace email in text.

Comment: @Mohammad what is the element looks like that <span>a@a.com<br>some text</span> . Wouldn't the <br> be removed?

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz That isn't a good think that you changed your question or your html after answering. Current code remove `br` from html but you can use `.html()` instead `.text()` that keep it.

Comment: @Mohammed, sorry for that. html() won't do, since it will return children that could potentially match the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find and replace texts, you can always use JQuery's `:contains` selector.
Like the example found here:
[Find text string using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)

You can get all occurrences of your desired string by using
`$('span:contains("bla@bla.com")` or even `*:contains` if you are not searching for a specific tag.

After you got all your instances, you can do a text replace, as suggested by Mohammad

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15765498)

Comment: Obvious issue I didn't have thought. Thanks for pointing it out!