# How blog contents are stored in database?

Tags: database, web, web-deployment, backend, blogs

I have a doubt in creating a blog. Take stackoverflow.com as example, In this, ask question or answer segment have a WYSIWYG like editor. If i use some href link or other html tags within my answer how the data format stored in database(In HTML or plain text or any other).

In case data is stored in HTML format, then how it is converted simple json for connecting with mobile app webservice's.

In simple question, In which format user data is stored in database and how it is used for further processing.

Comment: Databases are usually based on tables , it is stored in strings or ints , not html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it works on Stack Overflow, but I think the text is stored in database in plain text format but with special characters like:

`[link](http://example.com); _italic_; **bold**`

And then these symbols are replaced with actual markup

Comment: Is there any tool to convert to this format "[link](http://example.com); _italic_; **bold**"

Comment: JQuery is used for that, replace function. So you just get the text with symbols from database and replace for example ** with html tag <b></b> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886319/replace-text-in-html-page-with-jquery]

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro Lopushanskyy

Comment: If you accept my answer, it’ll be the best thanks you can give